# Can sunpanel be mounted to horizontal 2x4?

Tags: subpanel, installation

I read that subpanels should be mounted to a 3/4" backer board or secured directly to a stud.  Can I nail two 2x4s horizontally between two studs and secure the panel to those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can secure a Panel by any means necessary. The reason they should be mounted by a back board or vertical stud is to make sure you have the ability to run circuits to the Panel with as little interference as possible.

Just something to think about while you are in the planning stage. Good luck.

Comment: I thought the requirement of a backerboard was to provide for support of wires routed to the panel, and could be dispensed with if the panel was between studs.  Is this the case?  Or do I remember incorrectly?